# Blank Simulator screen for Xcode 9 beta 4 on Hackintosh 10.12.6

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, macos-sierra, xcode9-beta, hackintosh

I'm using hackintosh version of 10.12.6 and I already have Xcode 8.3.3 which works fine. Today I installed Xcode 9 beta 4 and when I try to run it, the simulator is giving me blank screen with weird graphics like in below image and it stays like that forever.

[image]

Things I tried as per other forums

```
1.Reinstall the Xcode beta
2.`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
3.Open Xcode and delete all the simulators using the Window > Devices window
4.Take a backup of `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/device_set.plist` and then remove the `com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0` key. 
5.Reinstall simulators within Xcode using the + in the lower-left of Window > Devices.
```

I've also removed my Xcode 8.3.3 just to ensure it doesn't create any conflict but still no luck. Any help is appreciated

Comment: FYI: Installing macOS on non-apple hardware is now illegal,
regarding the issue, i guess you can check out in your console logs and take it within any Hackintosh forums, could be driver issues ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using the Nvidia drivers.
Since Mac OS Sierra, some Applications require special signing from drivers, which Nvidia is not doing.
Because of this, some Applications only show blank windows, for example iBooks or Xcode Instruments. [You are not the only person with this "Bug".](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/solved-nvidia-web-driver-ibooks-bug.203229/page-22)
Since Xcode 9 Beta 3, Xcode needs the signing as well.
To fix the issues in all of those applications, you have to install this from github: [Kext to fix the problem.](https://github.com/mologie/NVWebDriverLibValFix/releases)
This fixed the problem for myself.

Comment: It's the cleanest fix I've read for this issue, thank you for sharing this! The kext works fine on my Hackintosh, just copied to Clover bootloader and did a restart. Before this, I used the codesign procedure for a long time but this method is much better and solves the root of the problem.

Comment: Great fix! Confirm working with 10.12.6 and latest nvidia drivers. Needs a reboot to load.

Comment: Worked for me on xCode 9.1 - Thanks!